# Using jQuery .trigger() method within iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to trigger a keydown event on an input element within an iframe, however it doesn't appear to be working:

```
var $$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var $ = jQuery = null;

$$('#myIframe').load(function () {
    $ = jQuery = window.frames[0].jQuery;

    ...

    var e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 68; 
    e.keyCode = 68;
    $('#myInput').trigger(e);
});
```

Similarly it doesn't seem possible to trigger other events, e.g.

```
$('#myInput').trigger('focus')
```

What's strange is that I **can** manipulate this input using other methods, e.g.

```
$('#myInput').focus();
$('#myInput').val('test');
```

... but .trigger() just doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a programatically defined `focus()` event? `trigger` doesn't trigger native functionality

Comment: is `#myInput` is inside iframe?

Comment: @TusharGupta sorry I should have been clearer - yes, #myInput is in the iframe

Comment: @tymeJV Good point - no, focus wasn't programmatically defined, which is why that wouldn't work. But... I had defined a keydown event elsewhere, so I'm guessing this should have theoretically worked. 

Just to be safe, I've also tried using [jquery-simulate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) which should be able to trigger native functionality as well... but this still doesn't work. I'm guessing there's just something dodgy going on in my code elsewhere that's affecting this.